# Angular 7 - rendering array of components

Tags: angular

I'm having some trouble understanding why I cant get my components to render. I have an array of strings that I would like to render has table head components.  However, when it is just rendering the whole array.

Here is my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableheader',
  templateUrl: './tableheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tableheader.component.css']
})
// This should be table header component
export class TableheaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() key
  @Input() value


  headers;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.headers = [];

    this.value.map((item, index) => this.headers.push(Object.keys(item)));
  }
}

----------------

<thead *ngFor="let header of headers">
  <th> {{ header }} </th>
</thead>
```

I would like them to render in a top-level table component.

Comment: what did you put as an input for this component?

Comment: It is an array of objects, with the value of headers being an array of the keys of those objects

Comment: you have decorated `key` and `value` with an `Input` decorator. What did you pass to the component when you called it?

Comment: I remove my comment, I was not thinking..

Comment: Can you try adding the markup `<pre>{{ headers | json}}</pre>`?
It will render the headers object to the page so that you can 'see' what's in it.

Please post back here if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.headers` will be array of arrays, when you loop over it you get whole array of headers from each object rendered.

```
const headers = [];
const value = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
value.map((item) => headers.push(Object.keys(item)));
console.log(headers);
// [['a'], ['b']]
```

You need to flatten your array `headers.flat()`.